# Read File from Each Folder Sequentially From Large Directory Python

Tags: python, list, subset, glob, readfile

I have been looking at lots of examples online of what I'm trying to do without a clear path forward. I need to use a wildcard to open a file with the same ending   as in *era5.wind that are located in a large directory of folders (~400). I need to open each folder, read the *era5.wind file, make some calculations, save each calcuation in a variable with the folder name, close the folder and file and do the same until the end of the folder list. My folders look like this:

[image]

What is the best pythonic way to read each folder from beginning to end and repeating the process for each file?
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=walk#os.walk) is what you're looking for here.